# Asp.Net Core Cannot access a disposed context instance

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to implement SignalR in order to consume data from a angular frontend application.

I've checked all the results on google that I can find, but I still can't solve my issue.

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this
> error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from
> dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context
> instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are
> calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using
> statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the
> dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances. Object name: 'AdminContext'

**Controller**

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ChartController : ControllerBase
{
    private IHubContext<ChartHub> _hub;
    private readonly ILiveMonitoringService _service;

    public ChartController(IHubContext<ChartHub> hub, ILiveMonitoringService service)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        _service = service;

    }
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var timerManager = new TimerManager(async () => await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferchartdata", await _service.GetAllAsync()));
        return Ok(new { Message = "Request Completed" });
    }
}
```

**Service**

```cs
public Task<List<LiveMonitoring>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return _repository.GetAll().Take(100).ToListAsync();
}
```

**Repository**

```cs
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        return _adminContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Couldn't retrieve entities");
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you please share starup.cs file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `TimerManager` is your issue. You did not show its declaration but looks like its constructor accepts a callback to be called ***at some later point of time***. And that's the issue. Your scoped service `_service` is captured in the callback and used at some later point of time ***when the request has already ended***. So after the request ended, the `DbContext` is disposed and your `_service` will consume a disposed context.

The fix is to simply get the data first before passing it into your callback so that the `_service` will not be captured into that callback, like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var liveMonitorings = await _service.GetAllAsync();
    var timerManager = new TimerManager(async () => await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferchartdata", liveMonitorings));
    return Ok(new { Message = "Request Completed" });
}
```

We need to change the returned type of `Get` to `Task<IActionResult>` to support `async` call.

If you actually want to call `_service.GetAllAsync()` at some time later (not at the time of requesting `Get`) inside the callback, you need to inject an `IServiceScopeFactory` to create a scope for your service inside that callback, like this:

```
public IActionResult Get([FromServices] IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    var timerManager = new TimerManager(async () => 
                           {
                             using(var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()){
                               var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILiveMonitoringService>();                                   ​
                               ​var liveMonitorings = await service.GetAllAsync();
                               ​return await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferchartdata", liveMonitorings);
                            ​ }
                           ​});
   ​return Ok(new { Message = "Request Completed" });
}
```

This way you don't need to inject your `_service` into the controller's constructor (because it's not used at all).
​